# Algorithm using recursion

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I am given three operation on integer:
A - add 3 to number
B - doubles the number
C - swaps two last digits of number
I am supposed to write algorithm that checks if i can make *k* prime number using operations A,B,C in *n* steps. At the end i have to print the sequence of operations that i used to make *k* prime number.
Lets assume we have function:

```
bool ifprime(int n);
```

The function `ifprime` returns true when the number is prime and return false when it is not.

The code:

```
bool is_possible(int k, int n, int a)
{
    if(ifprime(k))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(n==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            k = A(k); // perform operation A
            break;
        case 2:
            k=B(k); //perform operation B
            break;
        case 3:
            k=C(k); //perform operation C
            break;
    }
    return is_possible(k,n-1,1)||is_possible(k,n-1,2)||is_possible(k,n-1,3);
}
```

My problem is that i do not know how to remember the correct path and then print it.

Comment: at the time when you've detected the positive result print a message, after every recursive call if the return value is `true` print a message. once debugged replace "print a message" with appropriate output step

Comment: Did you mean enter "print message" 'if(ifprime(k)){cout << a; return true;}' I do not really understand. When i print message after detection i won't be able to print all steps. I would be extremely grateful if you could explain me this one more time.

Comment: every time your `is_possible()` is about to return `true`, including cases when it returns a value from the recursive call to itself, log the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an array `steps` of size `n` to your function as the forth parameter. Pass `N`, the total size of the array, as the fifth parameter. Put the value of `a` into `steps[N-n]` upon entering the function. Rather than returning `bool`, return an `int` that says how many steps it took to find a prime. If no prime has been found, return `-1`.

You need to return an `int` to know how many steps it took to come up with an answer in situations when it took less than `n` steps to reach a prime.

```
int is_possible(int k, int n, int a, int[] steps, int N) {
    if(ifprime(k))
    {
        return N-n;
    }
    if (!n)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    steps[N-n] = a;
    ...
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++) {
        int res = is_possible(k, n-1, i, steps, N);
        if (res != -1) return res;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that this approach may not be fast enough. You may need to [*memoize*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) your recursion.

Comment: I think i understood it, but i have question. "..." this three dots mean that code `switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            k = A(k); // perform operation A
            break;
        case 2:
            k=B(k); //perform operation B
            break;
        case 3:
            k=C(k); //perform operation C
            break;
    }` ?

Comment: @MarcinMajewski Yes - I did not want to copy the parts of your code that did not change. Did you check the link on memoization?

Comment: I checked and it was very useful to understand the idea of "memorization". I will try to use this in this code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use a switch case if u want to evaluate all possibilities. Here is a way to do what u intended :-

```
bool is_possible(int k,int n,int i,char* ch) {

    if(ifprime(k)) {
         ch[i] = '\0';
         return true;
    }

    if(n==0)
       return false;

    if(is_possible(A(k),n-1,i+1,ch)) {

        ch[i] = 'A';
        return true;
    }
    if(is_possible(B(k),n-1,i+1,ch)) {

        ch[i] = 'B';
        return true;
    }
    if(is_possible(C(k),n-1,i+1,ch)) {

        ch[i] = 'C';
        return true;
    }

   return false;

}

if(is_possible(3,5,0,ch))
      print(ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just print as you go (which is probably simplest way):

```
bool is_possible(int k, int n, int a)
{
    if(ifprime(k))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(n==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "n=" << n << " a = " << a << std::endl;
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            k = A(k); // perform operation A
            break;
        case 2:
            k=B(k); //perform operation B
            break;
        case 3:
            k=C(k); //perform operation C
            break;
    }
    return is_possible(k,n-1,1)||is_possible(k,n-1,2)||is_possible(k,n-1,3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool is_possible (int k,int n,int i,char* ch) {

    if(ifprime(k)) {
         ch[i] = '\0';
         return true;
    }

    if(n==0)
       return false;

    if(is_possible(A(k),n-1,i+1,ch)) {

        ch[i] = 'A';
        return true;
    }
    if(is_possible(B(k),n-1,i+1,ch)) {

        ch[i] = 'B';
        return true;
    }
    if(is_possible(C(k),n-1,i+1,ch)) {

        ch[i] = 'C';
        return true;
    }

   return false;

}

if(is_possible(3,5,0,ch))
      print(ch);
```

Comment: If you add a short description, your answer will get more attention. Thanks for your contribution!